# Asking a question "to", "from", or "of"?

Tags: questions

I was just talking with someone about the rule regarding "asking a question to/from/of".
I am natively Dutch, and to me, "to" makes the most sense intuitively, since in Dutch grammar you *pose* a question, you don't *ask* it. I'm aware however that "to" is incorrect in English.

The person I was talking to said that the correct rule is "from". This seems quirky to me however. If you "ask X from someone", it means that you ask them to give you an X. So to me, whereas "asking an answer from" makes sense, "asking a question from" doesn't, unless you're asking for a question.

I've seen a source on the internet that says "of" is the correct rule. But this sounds odd to both of us. "asking a question of X" sounds like you have a question about X.

So, which is the correct one, and why? Is my reasoning about "from" correct?

Comment: "To ask" already implies a question, which is similar to the Dutch verb "vragen", not so much "stellen" (to pose). In both Dutch and English, the default is to omit the preposition in that case. But similar as Dutch and English may be, prepositions are the major exception. My (native Dutch) mother invited the neighbor's kid and me (both 4 years old) to sit _on_ the table, and we happily complied ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have to use a preposition with *ask a question*, then of your choices, certainly it has to be *of*.

The thing is that normally, we wouldn’t use a preposition at all to name the person we’re posing the question to. Instead, we’d just use an indirect object, which must fall between the verb and the direct object:

- I’ll ask them three questions. [*indirect object*]
- I’ll ask three questions **of** them. [*prepositional object*]

Or like this:

- He asked them my name. [*indirect object*]
- He asked my name **of** them. [*prepositional object, but somewhat stilted*]

But remember, you also *ask someone **for** something*, which makes it more of a request instead of just questioning them:

- He asked them **for** my phone number.
- He requested my phone number **from** them.

Answer (score 21):

I can't find any references that really address this, but as a native English speaker, this is what sounds right to my ear:

Ask John a question.

Ask a question *of* John.

Pose a question *to* John.

Request a response to a question *from* John.

Comment: Or indeed "put a question to John".

Comment: "Request a response to a question from John" is ambiguous. Should the response be from John, or was the question asked by John?

Comment: "Ask a question from John" is wrong?

Comment: @Mich, yes, unless you want John to ask you a question.  The "for" is implied; "ask for a question from John" is more common.

Answer (score 7):

Ordinarily we use none of these: we say *ask a person/him/her a question*. But when we wish to express the person to whom the question is addressed with a preposition phrase, we use *of*: *ask a question **of** a person/him/her*.

Likewise, we *inquire **of*** someone what it is that we want to know. But as MrsLannister points out, this does not hold with other verbs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking someone "Who/whom do I ask about X", if you don't want to specify the subject, you could ask more generally "Who/whom do I ask questions of?"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This in no way answers the question - did you read it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417619)